# Can concepts(C++20) be used as a boolean?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

`using T = decltype(std::same_as<int, double>)`
I have tried this on VS2019. It turns out that `T = bool`.

Is this defined by standard, or just a property by specific compilers?
I haven't found any official information about it..
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *concept-id* like `std::same_as<int, double>` is evaluated like an expression. It produces a prvalue of type `bool`.

> **[temp.names]**
>
> [8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#8) A concept-id is a simple-template-id where the template-name is
> a concept-name. A concept-id is a prvalue of type bool, and does not
> name a template specialization. A concept-id evaluates to true if the
> concept's normalized constraint-expression is satisfied
> ([temp.constr.constr]) by the specified template arguments and false
> otherwise.

So `decltype` is reporting it correctly. In an expression, it's a `bool`.

Comment: BTW, your link is to the documentation of the standard concepts library. For the language feature, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Concepts - It mentions how as an expression it produces `true` or `false`. Hence the `bool` type is implied there.

Comment: You should add a TL;DR - **Yes**