# Would concepts possibly replace type traits in C++?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

I have already knew that concept is a compile-time predicate which can constrain templates or `auto`.

I have discovered that the concepts will return the prvalue of type `bool`, so I could print it to test myself.

I also read this specific question **[Can concepts(C++20) be used as a boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520935/can-conceptsc20-be-used-as-a-boolean)** and the answer which clarifies the concepts that can be used as boolean values.

> **[temp.names]**
> (8) A concept-id is a simple-template-id where the template-name is a concept-name. A concept-id is a prvalue of type bool, and does not name a template specialization. A concept-id evaluates to true if the concept's normalized constraint-expression is satisfied ([temp.constr.constr]) by the specified template arguments and false otherwise.

For example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept meowable = requires (T obj) {
    { obj.meow() } -> std::same_as<T&>;
};

struct Dog {};
struct Cat { Cat& meow(); };
struct Wolf { Wolf& woof(); };
```

Application:

```cpp
std::cout << std::boolalpha;

std::cout << "Has meow?" << '\n'
          << "Dog:  " << meowable<Dog>  << '\n'
          << "Cat:  " << meowable<Cat>  << '\n'
          << "Wolf: " << meowable<Wolf> << '\n';
```

Output:

```cpp
Has meow?
Dog: false
Cat: true
Wolf: false
```

I could also create type trait out of concepts:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct has_meow : std::bool_constant<meowable<T>> {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_meow_v = has_meow<T>::value;
```

Application:

```cpp
std::cout << "Has meow?" << '\n'
          << "Dog:  " << has_meow_v<Dog> << '\n'
          << "Cat:  " << has_meow_v<Cat> << '\n'
          << "Wolf: " << has_meow_v<Wolf> << '\n';
```

Which outputs the same as above.

From what I've learned about type traits, they are techniques that give an ability to inspect the "properties" of the type which includes compile-time predicate (not concepts, for example: `is_void`, `is_bounded_array`). They are part of "reflection" as of now if I'm not mistaken.

---

My main question is: Would concepts possibly replace type traits?

---

It seems like a cycle: concepts use type traits, and type traits may possibly use concepts.

- Will concepts help type traits to extend in the world of template metaprogramming?
- When do I apply these concepts or `requires` expressions as a "helper" / "competent" to type traits when "misused" as the same way `std::enable_if` did and maybe not used as a constraint. (It's fine for me if it's misused or applied indirectly to the language)

**NOTE:** I don't ask how is concepts used in a correct way, but I tried to ask if concepts possibly replace type traits in terms of the compile-time predicate.

Comment: I'm happy you're asking this question. It shows that you are getting deeper into C++ and thinking critically. Concepts are used in meta-programming (templates) to select the appropriate implementation of a class or function (or *not* select one). That said, it's a really broad question, and an adequate discussion may be out of scope.

Comment: So, you used this "stuffs" in your question.  And it asks how you can use it.  So, asked and answered?

Answer (score 0):

*(Note: this answer was written before OP started updating and expanding the original question)*

> When do I apply these kinds of stuff in C++?

The fact that a *concept-id* is a prvalue of type bool is essential when making use of concepts in the *constraint-logical-or-expression* of a *requires-clause*:

```
template<...>
void f() requires .... {}
//                ^^^^ - constraint-logical-or-expression 
//       
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - requires-clause
```

Where, particularly, as per [[temp.pre]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#nt:requires-clause), the grammar for a *requires-clause* is:

> ```
> requires-clause:
>   requires constraint-logical-or-expression
> ```

where *constraint-logical-or-expression*, in turn, is a [*primary-expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim#nt:primary-expression), which includes [*requires-expression*:s](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim#nt:requires-expression).

E.g. as in the following (contrived) example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept has_static_meow = requires (T obj) {
    { decltype(obj)::meow() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template <typename T>
concept has_static_bark = requires (T obj) {
    { decltype(obj)::bark() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

struct Dog { static void bark() { std::cout << "bark\n"; }};
struct Cat { static void meow() { std::cout << "meow\n"; } };

template<typename T>
struct MakeNoise {
    static void bark() requires has_static_bark<T> { T::bark(); }
    static void meow() requires has_static_meow<T> { T::meow(); }
};

int main() {
    MakeNoise<Dog>::bark();
    // MakeNoise<Dog>::meow(); // error with a nice error message
    MakeNoise<Cat>::meow();
    // MakeNoise<Cat>::bark(); // error with a nice error message
}
```

Comment: ... but you still need to literally answer OP's questions :-(

Comment: @einpoklum When I started on this answer I just read OP's version 1 (or possibly 2) of his question, where the main question (before the question exploded and changed) was "When do I apply these kinds of stuff in C++?".

Comment: I apologize if I asked in an inconsistent way but I tried to change my post every time on how I mean it.